# How to insert new rows from another table in between existing rows in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

So I have a table which looks like this (Let's call this `Table 1`):

| item | ingredients |
| --- | --- |
| tomato juice | tomato |
|  | water |
|  | sugar |

And I want to insert this to another table (Call this `Table 2`):

| menu item | ingredients |
| --- | --- |
| healthy set | tomato juice |
|  | salad |
|  | veggies |

So now I want to insert the ingredients of `tomato juice` to be inside of the `healthy set menu item` as such:

| menu item | ingredients |
| --- | --- |
| healthy set | tomato juice |
|  | **tomato** |
|  | **water** |
|  | **sugar** |
|  | salad |
|  | veggies |

How can I achieve this in BigQuery? I do not want to create a new column. Is this even possible?

Comment: Is ingredients column of type RECORD?

Comment: @BihagKashikar Nope it's not

Comment: ingredients from both table can be duplicate ? and is an order of ingredient in a merged array significant ?

Comment: as Jaytiger also asked, if order of ingredients is not significant, then isn't this a union on ingredient column.

Comment: @Jaytiger @Bihag Kashikar they cannot be duplicate. and the order is significant in a way where all the ingredients of `tomato juice` MUST be all below it (like the example given above).

Answer (score 1):

> they cannot be duplicate. and `the order is significant` in a way where all the ingredients of tomato juice MUST be all below it (like the example given above).

You might consider below.

```sql
WITH Table_1 AS (
  SELECT 'tomato juice' item, ['tomato', 'water', 'sugar'] ingredients
),
Table_2 AS (
  SELECT 'healthy set' menu_item, ['tomato juice', 'salad', 'veggies'] ingredients
)
SELECT menu_item, 
       (SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(
                 [i2] || IF(i2 = t1.item, t1.ingredients, [])
                 ORDER BY offset
               ) 
          FROM t2.ingredients i2 WITH offset
       ) AS ingredients
  FROM Table_2 t2 LEFT JOIN Table_1 t1 ON t1.item IN UNNEST(t2.ingredients);
```

**Query results**

[image]

- [ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG with ORDER BY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_concat_agg)